# I have an error in my query that says "unknown column in field list"

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting an error please help.
I wanted to insert my query results into the the table called current_tags but i keep getting #1054 - Unknown column 'customer_info.name' in 'field list' and i don'd understand where am i getting wrong.

```
INSERT INTO current_tags 
SELECT aisle_info.reader_id, 
       tag_no, 
       aisle_info.area, 
       customer_info.NAME, 
       Timestampdiff(second, Min(timestamp), Max(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME 
FROM   tag_logs 
       INNER JOIN aisle_info 
               ON tag_logs.reader_id = aisle_info.reader_id 
WHERE  tag_no = 3222813112261
```

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'customer_info.name' in 'field list'

Comment: where is your customer_info table?

Comment: My customer_info table is there in my database

Comment: I am asking in the above query, if you used a column from that table then you should need to use it as join or as your need

Comment: What @M.Hemant is saying is that the table `customer_info` is not joined in your query. If you want to use a field from it, you must join that table.

Comment: I didn't get your question, could you please elaborate?

Comment: This is my query, INSERT INTO current_tags
SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID, tag_no, aisle_info.area, customer_info.name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME FROM tag_logs INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID 
WHERE tag_no = 3222813112261 I have customer_info there.

Comment: You are using `customer_info` as table alias of `name` but it is not available since you `INSERT INTO current_tags`

Comment: In my current_tags table i have a column called 'name', so just like how i brought aisle_info.reader_id from the aisle_info table, the same way i wanna take in name from the customer_info table. Help

Comment: What you have tried? How we can join `current_tags` with `customer_info`? We need more information to help you. We don't know the database and tables.

Comment: @AndrewYochem could you please help me in joining the tables, because i tried and i got error

Comment: @sebastianBroach yes i do have all the fields necessary

Comment: My current_tags table has the following columns :reader_id, tag_no, area, name_maxtime. My customer_info has the following columns: name, email. My aisle_info has the following colomns : reader_id, area, Lastly my tag_logs has the following columns, reader_id, tag_no, timestamp

Comment: And what is the relationship between `current_tags` and `customer_info`?

Comment: I want to get the 'name' from the customer_info and put it in current_tags through this query just the same way how i used aisle_info.reader_id i called it in the query itself and that works, how it is that when i put customer_info and current_tags it doesnt work?

Comment: You are using `aisle_info` on the `FROM ... JOIN ...`. You are **not** using `customer_info` on the `FROM ... JOIN ... ` this is the reason why it is not working.

Comment: I tried this : INSERT INTO current_tags
SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID, tag_no, aisle_info.area, customer_info.name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME FROM tag_logs INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID AND customer_info INNER JOIN current_tags ON customer_info.name = customer_info.name
WHERE tag_no = 3222813112261     #1052 - Column 'tag_no' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I tried this as well INSERT INTO current_tags
SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID, tag_no, aisle_info.area,customer_info.name(customer_info JOIN current_tags ON customer_info.name = customer_info.name), TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME FROM tag_logs INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID 
WHERE tag_no = 3222813112261 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN current_tags ON customer_info.name = customer_info.name), TIMESTAMPDIFF

Comment: @M.Hemant i tried with the join command as well but i am getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using **customer_info** table in query so check your query.

Comment: could you please help me with the query? or the join command to join the customer_info table with the current tags?

Comment: Check customer_info table relation table to other table then you can join that columns.